# Pandas dataframe combine two or more rows and add values of specific columns in these rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and i need to combine two or more rows and add values of specific column for these rows.

Below is an example of the dataframe exported to csv

```
symbol,orderId,price,qty,time,isBuyer
TRXUSDT,60180710.0,0.03028,429.4,2019-05-15 05:10:03,SELL
TRXUSDT,60180710.0,0.03025,10000.0,2019-05-15 05:10:03,SELL
TRXUSDT,60180710.0,0.03024,3856.2,2019-05-15 05:10:03,SELL
TRXUSDT,60180710.0,0.03026,14630.6,2019-05-15 05:10:03,SELL
```

Above rows have the same symbol, orderId, time and isBuyer columns.
But they have different "qty", and "price".

I would like to combine it into one row and sum the "qty" values into one single value, and the average of "price" values into single value

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `df.groupby(['symbol', 'orderId', 'time', 'isBuyer']).agg({'qty': sum, 'price': 'mean'})`

Comment: @J.Doe that returns qty and price only as below qty,price
488.1,1.028995
1055.0,1.15281